# Unrepeated colors in multiple line plots using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, color-mapping

I have 20 columns to plot using unrepeated colors. I would like to use `tab20` color map. How do I use it?

I am finding all the online resources difficult to understand as I am still naive Python user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general this is how you can do it:

```
import matplotlib
cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap(your_cmap) #your_cmap='tab20'
df.plot(cmap=cmap)
plot.show()
```

Here you can find the references: https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help:) please consider to accept the answer by clicking in the tick on the left :)